Whitney's Approximation Theorem for Continous maps


I am trying to understand this proof from Lee's Smooth Manifolds.
How do we know for any $y \in M -A$, $\tilde{F}$ is still smooth? For example, if we are only on $U_1$, then
$$\tilde{F}(y) = \phi_1(y)F(x_1)$$, but $F(x_i)$ could be non-smooth.
Also finally, what does the continuity of $\delta$ have to do with getting a bound on $|F(y) - F(x_i)| < \delta(x)/2$

You have to be careful about which of the variables are really variables and which of them are fixed. For smoothness of $\tilde F$ on $U_1$, the point $x_1$ is fixed, so $y\mapsto \phi_1(y)F(x_1)$ is just a constant multiple of the smooth function $\phi_1$ and hence smooth. Similarly, in the general formula for $\tilde F$, the points $x_i$ are fixed so for each $i$, $F(x_i)$ is just a real number that you multiply the smooth function $\phi_i$ by. Then smoothness of the sum follows directly from the fact that the supports of the $\phi_i$ are locally finite.
In the other question, continuity of $\delta$ is not needed to get the estimate on $|F(y)-F(x)|$, you just need that $\delta_1(x)$ is a positive number. The continuity of $\delta$ is only needed for the estimate on $|\delta(y)-\delta(x)|$.

This might be a basic question, but I thought $\tilde{F}$ being smooth is a result of just summing up smooth functions. What does the supports of $\phi_i$ being locally finite have to do with it?

For an infinite sum of smooth functions convergence is not a simple issue and even if the sum does converge, it is not smooth in general. But if the supports of the functions involved in the sum are locally finite (which is ensured by the requirement on the supports of the $\phi_i$), then locally around each point, the sum coincides with a finite sum of smooth functions and hence is convergent and smooth.
